# grep search find . in files with .txt extension only

Tags: search, ubuntu, grep, filenames

```
    find . | xargs grep "Book" -sl | xargs grep -inw "Stars" -sl
```

this returns the filename of the files that contain words "Book" and "Stars".
How do you modify this so that you could search only *.txt files ?
Also is there a way to specify the search directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Without using too many options(such as : -iname,-inw ,. so on):

```
locate /*txt | xargs grep -rl Book | xargs grep -rl Stars
```

That is it .

**UPDATE :**

If you want to specify your directory . take this example :

- Directory = `/home/corbett/Documents`

Thus ,

```
locate /home/corbett/Documents/*txt |xargs grep -rl Book |xargs grep -rl Stars
```

If the search is not case sensitive , use `-i` option for `grep` cmd:

```
locate /home/corbett/Documents/*txt |xargs grep -i -rl Book |xargs grep -i -rl Stars
```

**Locate vs Find :**

- `Find` is more efficient for the new files .
- `Locate` is the fastest as it handle database of strings(files paths)

Comment: I don't seem to have a program called locate?  Is it a POSIX thing?  If it isn't what OS do I need to install to get it?  If it requires a certain OS you should specify which one in the answer.

Comment: Dear , it is a question from ubuntu user. revise Q tags . Thx

Comment: somehow, locate is taking forever to give the result. don't we need quotation for the word to be searched. also, is the search case sensitive?

Comment: yes it is . if you don't want case sensitive ,use -i option with grep , i will update my answer

Comment: Note also that locate is the fastest . try and we are waiting ur feedback . if you find this answer is not useful, tell us please to delete it

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `-iname` parameter. It makes `find` search all files with extension "`.txt`" (case-insensitive). Also add the `-type f` parameter to ensure you are only searching files (this should allow you to remove the -s "suppress error" parameter passed to `grep`).

```
find . -iname "*.txt" -type f | xargs grep "Book" -sl | xargs grep -inw "Stars" -sl
```

You can also use `-exec` parameter instead.

```
find . -iname "*txt" -type f -exec grep "Book" -lZ {} \; | xargs -0 grep -inw "Stars" -l
```

The `-Z` parameter for `grep` and the `-0` parameter for `xargs` ensures that filenames piped from one to the other work even if they have spaces in them.

Comment: And you can replace the `.` with another directory to search in. The `.` just means the current directory.

Comment: Instead of a pipe you can also use -exec, should be more robust with filenames then.

Comment: But that's wrong -- it looks for either of the search strings, not both.

Comment: @tripleee, You're right - nice catch. Changed it to `find . -iname "*txt" -type f -exec grep "Book" -l {} \; | xargs grep -inw "Stars" -l` however, this doesn't look as clean anymore, even though it's a bit more efficient than the non-exec version.